# The output keeps repeating through the array

Tags: java, arrays, numbers, min, minimum

The purpose of this code is to prompt the user for ten numbers, put the numbers in an array, decide what number in that array is the minimum number, and display "The minimum number is: [minimum number]." My code basically does what it's suppose to, but when it comes to the output it gives a 0.0 value throughout the entire array until the end, which is then when it gives the minimum number. I don't understand why this is happening and have tried everything I can think of to fix it, but nothing seems to work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question7_9 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] array = new double[10];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter ten numbers: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = input.nextDouble();
            new Question7_9().min(array);
        }
    }

    public static void min(double[] array) {
        double m = array[0];
        for (int i = 1; i <= array.length - 1; i++) {
            if (m > array[i]) {
                m = array[i];   
            }
        }
        System.out.print("The minimum number is: " + m);

    }

}
```

Comment: Take a look at quick sort. This is a well known sorting algorithm that will take your array and sort it. You can then display the first index of the array as its sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You should find the minimum after initializing the entire array (i.e. after the for loop) :

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = input.nextDouble();
}
new Question7_9().min(array);
```

If you call the `min` method within the loop, you'll search for the minimum `array.length` times, and in all but the last time you'll be searching the minimum in an array that still has some default `0.0` values, so the minimum will be `0.0` unless you input some negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are running the `min(array)` method each time the user inputs a number.

Just write the line `new Question7_9().min(array);` after the `for` loop.

Here is the complete running program,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question7_9 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] array = new double[10];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter ten numbers: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = input.nextDouble();

        }
        new Question7_9().min(array);
    }

    public static void min(double[] array) {
        double m = array[0];
        for (int i = 1; i <= array.length - 1; i++) {
            if (m > array[i]) {
                m = array[i];   
            }
        }
        System.out.print("The minimum number is: " + m);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few points worth noting:

- You don't need to create a new `Question7_9` object just to call the `min` method. It is `public` `static` so you can just use `Question7_9.min` or even just `min` because you are calling it inside the same class.
- In your case it doesn't really need to be `static` or `public`. It's worth getting used to getting the access control correct.
- There is a shorthand syntax for the `for` statement when used with arrays: `for (double val: array)`
- You can use `Math.min` to get the smaller of two values rather than using an `if` statement
- It makes more sense to have `min` return the minimum value rather than print it.

  - The `min` method will throw an exception on an empty array. Best to check for this or have a default value (such as Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);

Putting all of that together:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question7_9 {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] array = new double[10];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter ten numbers: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = input.nextDouble();
        }
        System.out.println("The minimum number is " + min(array));
    }

    private double min(double[] array) {
        double min = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        for (double value: array) {
            min = Math.min(min, value);
        }
        return min;
    }
}
```

And just to give you a taste of how simple this sort of thing can be with Java 8 streams:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
DoubleStream.generate(input::nextDouble).limit(10).min()
    .ifPresent(min -> System.out.println("The minimum number is " + min));
```